# ¿para que sirve $. en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

he visto mucho este símbolo `$` en librerías de JavaScript, por ejemplo:

```
$.fn._fadeIn = $.fn.fadeIn;
```

Comment: Compañero, si la respuesta te ha servido marcala como valida, un saludo

Answer (score 8):

Hace referencia a métodos de las bibliotecas de JavaScript más populares (jQuery, ProtoType...) `$` es simplemente un identificador de JavaScript válido.

Prototype, jQuery y la mayoría de las bibliotecas javascript utilizan el `$` como el objeto base primario (o función). La mayoría de ellos también tienen una forma de renunciar al `$` para que pueda ser usado con otra biblioteca que lo use. En ese caso, usas jQuery en lugar de `$`. De hecho, `$` es solo un atajo para jQuery.